# Will increasing the size of six shower head branches improve flow?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe

I have currently 1/2 inch branches running into 6 shower jets. However, the upper jets don't get enough water deployment. Would changing the branches 1/2 inch to 3/4 inch pipe make difference?

Comment: Similar: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/can-a-%C2%BD-inch-water-pipe-supply-enough-pressure-for-a-shower-head-and-body-spraye

Comment: I would bet that installation instructions for this multi-head shower describing how to set the relative flows was included with the 6 heads.  It is even possible that a set of flow restrictors of a range of resistances was in with shower heads. Google this model and ask about setting relative flows.

Comment: Yeah, increasing the pipe size is not the way to go. I'd get a dedicated pressurized tank just for your shower. I mean 6 heads? Tell me, when you cut off a few heads (or are you able to do that) does the water pressure increase? I'll be it does. This is a specialized plumbing thingy where you need to give it its own water and water pressure. Or increase your main pressure tank. Are you on city water or your own well? – stormy 1 hour ago

Comment: Like landscape irrigation, we all went to 1" pipe.  Gees, we used to have to dictate pipe size for water pressure!  But here is the gig, one has to have ZONES that only allow a certain number of heads to operate and put out water.  6 heads is a lot of outlets and will most definitely produce. low low pressure if one doesn't design that into the plumbing.  What happens when you flush the toilet and you are showering?  Who installed the shower heads?  They should have known that things had to be redesigned....

Comment: Or you might have to use a dedicated PUMP to increase the pressure?  I think a dedicated pressure tank will solve your problems...need to know if you are on city water (usually 60 psi) or on your own well.  Do you have a cistern in line with your system?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. You'd still be limited by the bottleneck in the system which is the half-inch supply line. It depends on how it's branched, though. If you can fit a manifold such that no branch is downstream of another you might see some improvement. In that case I wouldn't use 3/4" pipe. You'd see no benefit.

```
           ||
           ||
 =====================
 ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
```

Comment: The valve could be the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

Many, and I would bet all, of these fixtures have plastic disc flow restrictors in them. To balance the flow you would ream out the restrictors in the lines that are not delivering sufficient flow and/or replace the flow restrictors in the lines that are giving too much with restrictors which are more limiting.

[Plastic disc flow restrictors](https://www.google.com/search?q=plastic%20disc%20flow%20restrictor&biw=1094&bih=487&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjS6bTvlN7RAhUp64MKHZBuAD4QsAQIJw)

Or you could insert an adjustable metering valve into each line (or some of them) to tune the relative outputs of the jets.
[Adjustable flow metering valve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NniAq.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NniAq.jpg)